# kubectl wait - error: no matching resources found

Tags: kubectl, metallb

I am installing metallb, but need to wait for resources to be created.

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready --timeout=60s -n metallb-system --all pods
```

But I get:

```
error: no matching resources found
```

If I dont wait I get:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "STDIN": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "ipaddresspoolvalidationwebhook.metallb.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://webhook-service.metallb-system.svc:443/validate-metallb-io-v1beta1-ipaddresspool?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.106.91.126:443: connect: connection refused
```

Do you know how to wait for resources to be created before actually be able to wait for condition.

Info:

```
kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.4", GitCommit:"872a965c6c6526caa949f0c6ac028ef7aff3fb78", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-11-09T13:36:36Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.4", GitCommit:"872a965c6c6526caa949f0c6ac028ef7aff3fb78", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-11-09T13:29:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}
```

Comment: What kubernetes version are you using ? What is the output of kubectl get pods?

Comment: Added kubectl version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error **“no matching resources found”:**

Wait for a minute and try again, It will be resolved.

You can find the explanation about that error in the following link [Setting up Config Connector](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/policy-compliant-resources#setting_up)

**For the error STDIN:**

**Follow the steps mentioned below:**

You are getting this error because **API server is NOT able to connect to the webhook**

1)Check your Firewall Rules allowing TCP port 443 or not.

2)Temporarily disable the operator

```
  kubectl -n config-management-system scale deployment config-management-operator --replicas=0
    deployment.apps/config-management-operator scaled
```

Delete the deployment

```
kubectl delete deployments.apps  -n <namespace> -system <namespace>-controller-manager
deployment.apps "namespace-controller-manager" deleted
```

3)create a configmap in the default namespace

```
kubectl create configmap foo
configmap/foo created
```

4)Check that configmap does not work with the label on the object

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    configmanagement.gke.io/debug-force-validation-webhook: "true"
  name: foo
EOF
```

Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "STDIN": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "debug-validation.namespace.sh": failed to call webhook: Post "https://namespace-webhook-service.namespace-system.svc:443/v1/admit?timeout=3s": no endpoints available for service "namespace-webhook-service"

5)And finally do clean up by using the below commands :

```
kubectl delete configmap foo
configmap "foo" deleted

kubectl -n config-management-system scale deployment config-management-operator --replicas=1
deployment.apps/config-management-operator scaled
```